# Analyze growth using graphs

Tags: geometry

How do I analyze growth using only graphs (and no exact values)?

I want to show that the first growth is cubic, the second is square and the third is linear.

As far as I know the third one can be considered linear as I could find a linear equation to describe it (using a slope triangle), but what about the other two?

[image]

Comment: You could use a least square fit (polynomial regression) for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to describe your first and second graphs in terms of a quadratic, repsectively.

For the first graph, find at least $4$ points on your graph.

Then, construct the following equation:

$$y = ax^3+b^2+cx+d$$

Plug in your values and solve for the unknowns to get the equation.

Similarly, you can perform the same procedure with your second graph with only $3$ points.

And also using the equation:

$$y = ax^2+bx+c$$

**Another alternative approach** could be that you can use software such as Wolfram-Alpha or a graphing calculator or even Microsoft Excel to plot your graph and find the equation for you. Its more efficient than the first method stated above.

Comment: my problem is that those are experimental values, so they are only approximations and I probably won't find any "clean" solution.